# leadsheets verse numbering with custom template Verse Number not in front of lyrics

Tags: songs, leadsheets

Using the example of custom verse template in page 41, I wanted to try the flush left template.  However, the verse number is not on the same line as the lyric line.  It is in the chord line.  I want the verse number in front of the lyric line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leadsheets}


\defineversetypetemplate{flushleft}
{%
    
    \noindent\llap{\verselabel\space}%
    \flushleft
    \unskip
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \ifobeylines
    {%
        \setlength\parskip{0pt}
         \setleadsheets{ obey-lines-parskip = .5\baselineskip }
         }
     {%
         \setlength\parskip{.5\baselineskip}
         \vspace*{-0.5\parskip}
         }%
     }
 
{\endflushleft}

\setleadsheets{print-chords=true, chorus*/format = \bfseries}


\begin{document}
    \begin{song}[verse/numbered, remember-chords]{
            title={Reprehenderit in Voluptate Velit}%
        }
        \begin{chorus*}[template=flushleft]
            LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur ADIPIS^*{E}CING \\
            elit, ^{A}sed do eiusmod tempor ^{B7}incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a^{E}liqua LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur ADIPIS^*{E}CING 
        \end{chorus*}
        
        \begin{verse}[template=flushleft]
            Ent^{A}rad en su presencia con can^{E}tares, can^{B}tares de alegría a nuestro D^{E}ios ^{E7} \\
            Ent^{A}rad en su presencia con can^{E}tares, can^{B}tares de alegría a nuestro Dios.
        \end{verse}
        
        \begin{verse}[template=flushleft]
            ^Sabed que el Señor es nuestro ^Dios que ^nos hizo y somos suyos^. ^{} \\
            ^Sabed que somos su pu^eblo y las ov^ejas de su rebaño.
        \end{verse}
    \end{song}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flushleft` template indeed just prints the verse label and then moves the text down if chords are printed. A workaround is to add a line of vertical space, then print the label, and then add negative vertical space to keep the position where it was before.

Of course this should only be done when actually printing chords. For this you can expose the internal boolean associated to the `print-chords` option, which is `\l__leadsheets_chord_print_bool`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \ifprintchords {}
  { \bool_if:NTF \l__leadsheets_chord_print_bool }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineversetypetemplate{flushleft}
{%
    \ifprintchords{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}{}%
    \noindent\llap{\verselabel\space}%
    \ifprintchords{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}{}%
    \flushleft
    \unskip
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \ifobeylines
    {%
        \setlength\parskip{0pt}
         \setleadsheets{ obey-lines-parskip = .5\baselineskip }
         }
     {%
         \setlength\parskip{.5\baselineskip}
         \vspace*{-0.5\parskip}
         }%
     }
 
{\endflushleft}

\setleadsheets{print-chords=true, chorus*/format = \bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \begin{song}[verse/numbered, remember-chords]{
            title={Reprehenderit in Voluptate Velit}%
        }
        \begin{chorus*}[template=flushleft]
            LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur ADIPIS^*{E}CING \\
            elit, ^{A}sed do eiusmod tempor ^{B7}incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a^{E}liqua LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur ADIPIS^*{E}CING 
        \end{chorus*}
        
        \begin{verse}[template=flushleft]
            Ent^{A}rad en su presencia con can^{E}tares, can^{B}tares de alegría a nuestro D^{E}ios ^{E7} \\
            Ent^{A}rad en su presencia con can^{E}tares, can^{B}tares de alegría a nuestro Dios.
        \end{verse}
        
        \begin{verse}[template=flushleft]
            ^Sabed que el Señor es nuestro ^Dios que ^nos hizo y somos suyos^. ^{} \\
            ^Sabed que somos su pu^eblo y las ov^ejas de su rebaño.
        \end{verse}
    \end{song}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that while adding and subtracting vertical space is done elsewhere in the custom templates as well, it is not a very clean solution in my opinion. Maybe the package author Clemens (who is a regular here on TeX.SE) can provide a nicer solution - a possibility might be some sort of `\printlabel` command that would delay the printing of the label until it is known what the correct position is.